# How to get IP of outside connection using telnet, or perhaps misconfiguration of memcached allowed ip's

Tags: linux, bash, networking, memcached

Server A with memcached, Server B needs to use memcached. If I leave memcached open to all ips (default), Server B can:

```
telnet server.a.etc 11211
```

and get in. If I ping server B, I get an ip, 153.353.234.23 (example), and I put that in my memcached options

```
OPTIONS="-l 153.353.234.23"
```

restart and now server b can't connect over telnet any longer. I assume this is because perhaps it is using a different ip address for this connection? Some other error? Either way, I'd like to be able to see the ip of server B when it connects.

I enabled memcached logging

```
-vvv >var/log/memcached.log 2>&1
```

and I see logs getting generated, but not the ip addresses of connecting machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with memcached -l you are instructing the memcached server to bind on a specific IP address of the server. This is useful if you want memcached to accept data on a specific IP or network interface on your server node.
You can leave the default to make memcached bind on any IP address of the server (0.0.0.0 on IPv4).

I don't think memcached has a command switch to login the source IP.
You can use the command

```
netstat -natp | grep 11211 | grep ESTABLISHED
```

on a linux system to get the established connections to memcached and the IPs of the clients.

Comment: ok, so the yes, running that command I see connections coming through from the 153.353.234.23 address, so that's not the problem, but you're saying that -l option doesn't even do that, it's binding local addresses. There two servers are running within the same server farm, how would I secure memcached to just accept connections from server B? I can open a new question if you want too-

Comment: @chrismarx you can use iptables if you are running memcached on a linux system. iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 11211 -s ! [ip_client] -j DROP

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
telnet telnetmyip.com
```

also

```
ssh telnetmyip.com
```

also

```
curl telnetmyip.com
```